# how to use LinearLayout instead of CheckedTextView in android Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

i want to implement listview with LinearLayout item (it will contain CheckedTextView and multiple textview).
so i want use LinearLayout instead of CheckedTextView in ListView. 
i tried but the radio button state is not changing.
my code:

```
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    getListView().setItemsCanFocus(false);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,android.R.id.text1,COUNTRIES));
```

list_item

```
 <CheckedTextView
        .....
        />
```

i want like this 
list_item_new

```
<LinearLayout>
        .....
        <CheckedTextView/>
        <TextView/>
.....
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customise the way list items are appearing, you'll need to implement your own adapter.  It's much simpler than you think.  Here's the basic code for you:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List myData;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, List data) {
        context = ctx;
         myData = data;
    }

    public int getCount() { return myData.size(); }

    public Object getItem(int pos) { return myData.itemAt(pos); }

    public int getItemId(int pos) { return pos; }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //this is where you create your own view with whatever layout you want
        LinearLayout item;
        if(convertView == null) {
            //create/inflate your linear layout here
            item = ...;
        }
        else {
            item = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }

        //now create/set your individual components inside your layout based on your element
        //at the requested position
        ...
    }
}
```

and that's all it is to it.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem. The problem was that a CheckedTextView inside a LinearLayout does not change state when pressed?

Comment: @GlennBech Have you tried this?  I have - and it works as desired.

Comment: I have tried to use a LinearLayout with a nested checkedTextView inflated by a CursorAdapter. That does not work, and is why I ended up on this page. Why should a custom adapter work? the root of the problem is that LinearLayout does not implement the Checkable interface? (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html)

Comment: correct Glenn Bech. i have implemented using on onItemClick based on Aleks answer. but my question is **how to implement linear layout instead of checkedTextView?. Is it possible?**